# setState from Promise values inside loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios, es6-promise

I am using React with axios to make an external API call, loop through each object in the array passed back API call. Inside loop, I have a promise that has called another function that returns an object. I want to use the values from this object returned an assign them to a variable outside the loop that is an array used to set state but I can't seem to do so as it's always empty? Hopefully the comments in my code below help you understand my issue.

```
let self = this;
this.instance.get('/fixtures?timeFrame=n1').then((fixtures) => {
  // get all fixtures
  const allFixtures = fixtures.data.fixtures;
  // create valid fixtures array to add all fixture details to pass to fixtures state
  let validFixtures = [];
  // loop through all fixture objects in allFixtures array
  for (var i = 0; i < (allFixtures.length); i++) {
    // check if valid fixture, returns true or false
    let isValid = self.isValid(allFixtures[i]);
    // if fixture is valid
    if (isValid) {
      // get id of fixture to pass through to fixture route with id query
      let fixtureId = allFixtures[i]._links.self.href.split('v1/')
        .pop();
      // home teams name
      let homeTeam = allFixtures[i].homeTeamName;
      // away teams name
      let awayTeam = allFixtures[i].awayTeamName;
      // call head2head function to get all previous results from the two teams playing and returns average score
      // returns as object, example: { 'homeTeamAvgScore': 2, 'awayTeamAvgScore': 1 }
      self.getHead2Head(fixtureId, homeTeam,
        awayTeam).then((avg) => {
        //in here i want to push object into validFixtures array along with homeTeam and awayTeam as named values
        return validFixtures.push({
          'homeTeam': homeTeam,
          'awayTeam': awayTeam,
          'homeTeamAvgScore': avg.homeTeamAvgScore,
          'awayTeamAvgScore': avg.awayTeamAvgScore
        })
      });
    }
  }
  //validFixtures is empty??? 
  //How else can push to array and then later setState to fixtures with validFixtures array???
  self.setState({
    fixtures: validFixtures
  });
}).catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
}
```

Comment: Add a "return" keyword before self.getHead2Head, it should solve your problem

Comment: @GaneshKarewad This appears to stop looping after the 3rd iteration. The length of the `allFixtures` array is 34 but only loops 3 times?

Comment: Should be
   return Promise.all(allFixtures,(fixture) =>{ 
  //
  let homeTeam = fixture.homeTeam
  let awayTeam = fixture.awayTeam

  return self.getHead2Head(fixtureId, homeTeam, awayTeam).then((avg) =>   {  return validFixtures.push({ 'homeTeam': homeTeam, 'awayTeam': awayTeam, 'homeTeamAvgScore': avg.homeTeamAvgScore, 'awayTeamAvgScore': avg.awayTeamAvgScore }) });
 })

You will probably have to modify this code because I'm answering this on a mobile phone without js compiler or intrepreter. I hope it helps

Comment: Long story short use return promise.all instead of a for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific requirement is known as a barrier. That is, you want to wait until `n` number of tasks have finished, and then do something. The "wait till n number of tasks finish" part can be achieved using the barrier.

If you use Promises, this can be easily done using `Promise.all`. Axios exposes promise interfaces.

If you don't want to use Promises, you either have to use something like the `async` npm library or implement a barrier by your own.

UPDATE:

`Async - Await` is not the same as `Promise.all` as mentioned in one of the other answers. The method suggested can degrade performance as the loop will run synchronously one after the other. This is explained clearly in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Example Fix,

```
this.instance.get('/fixtures?timeFrame=n1')
    .then((fixtures) => {
        // ...Same code as yours
        const allFixtures = fixtures.data.fixtures;
        let promises = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < (allFixtures.length); i++) {
            // ... Same code as yours
            if (isValid) {
                // ... Same code as yours

                // Don't call "then". We will resolve these promises later
                promises.push(this.getHead2Head(fixtureId, homeTeam, awayTeam));
            }
        }

        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(averages=>{
                let validFixtures = averages.map((avg, index)=>{
                    return {
                        'homeTeam': allFixtures[index].homeTeamName,
                        'awayTeam': allFixtures[index].awayTeamName,
                        'homeTeamAvgScore': avg.homeTeamAvgScore,
                        'awayTeamAvgScore': avg.awayTeamAvgScore
                    };
                });
                this.setState({
                    fixtures: validFixtures
                });
            });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Few Side Notes:

1. You don't need the `self` variable here. `this` scope is not changed as long as you use arrow functions(`=>`) instead of the `function` keyword.
2. The way I've indented `then` resolves are a bit different. That is only because it seems more readable to me

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm still a little unsure where I need to do the Promise.all exactly, is it instead of a for loop as suggested by @Ganesh Karewad?

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me understand promises a lot more!

Comment: Only issue with this is that, for example, the first iteration of the for loop is not valid and the second one is, when doing the map of `averages` the index of `0` will equal the first iteration even though it was not valid.

Answer (score 1):

`.then` handler is always being called asynchronously. So, in your case `validFixtures.push()` will execute later (sic!) than `self.setState({ fixtures: validFixtures });`

How to fix:

1) Old JS way.

```
  let validFixtures = [];
  let promieses = [];
  for (...) {
    ...
      promises.push(self.getHead2Head(fixtureId, homeTeam,
        awayTeam).then((avg) => {
        //in here i want to push object into validFixtures array along with homeTeam and awayTeam as named values
        return validFixtures.push({
          'homeTeam': homeTeam,
          'awayTeam': awayTeam,
          'homeTeamAvgScore': avg.homeTeamAvgScore,
          'awayTeamAvgScore': avg.awayTeamAvgScore
        })
      }));
    ...
  }

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    self.setState({
      fixtures: validFixtures
    });
  });
```

2) Modern JS way (note `async` and `await` keywords):

```
let self = this;
this.instance.get('/fixtures?timeFrame=n1').then(async (fixtures) => {
    // get all fixtures
    const allFixtures = fixtures.data.fixtures;
    // create valid fixtures array to add all fixture details to pass to fixtures state
    let validFixtures = [];
    // loop through all fixture objects in allFixtures array
    for (var i = 0; i < (allFixtures.length); i++) {
        // check if valid fixture, returns true or false
        let isValid = self.isValid(allFixtures[i]);
        // if fixture is valid
        if (isValid) {
            // get id of fixture to pass through to fixture route with id query
            let fixtureId = allFixtures[i]._links.self.href.split('v1/')
                .pop();
            // home teams name
            let homeTeam = allFixtures[i].homeTeamName;
            // away teams name
            let awayTeam = allFixtures[i].awayTeamName;
            // call head2head function to get all previous results from the two teams playing and returns average score
            // returns as object, example: { 'homeTeamAvgScore': 2, 'awayTeamAvgScore': 1 }
            const avg = await self.getHead2Head(fixtureId, homeTeam, awayTeam);
            //in here i want to push object into validFixtures array along with homeTeam and awayTeam as named values
            validFixtures.push({
                'homeTeam': homeTeam,
                'awayTeam': awayTeam,
                'homeTeamAvgScore': avg.homeTeamAvgScore,
                'awayTeamAvgScore': avg.awayTeamAvgScore
            });
        }
    }
    //validFixtures is empty??? 
    //How else can push to array and then later setState to fixtures with validFixtures array???
    self.setState({
        fixtures: validFixtures
    });
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```